# Why are droid parts so rare?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've been saving up all my credits to outfit some of my companions and I've noticed that droid parts seem to be really rare in the game.

Why is this? I thought that a crafting profession could make parts? At the moment I'm getting by using the mission reward items.

Comment: Cybertech *can* make droid parts. They're probably just not a market for them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because droid parts were removed from the game in Patch 4.0 -- now droid companions only use weapons and have no other gear slots.  As such, this is no longer a concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Cybertech" ability can make droid parts.  My guess is that you're finding fewer of these parts for sale because droids aren't playable, whereas most (all?) other companions overlap with the playable classes.  They also seem to drop more rarely, presumably for the same reason, but it's anyone's guess as to BioWare's intentions here.

One good way to get parts (besides specializing in Cybertech yourself) would be to join a guild and request one of your guildmates with Cybertech to craft some for you.

Comment: I disagree that they aren't playable. T7 is an able companion!

Comment: @DavidYell, I think in this context Matthew is saying that droids aren't a player race - you can't roll a droid character.

Comment: Oh right sorry, I misunderstood. In fact is T7 the only droid companion, excluding your ship droid.

Comment: @DavidYell: A year late, but you forgot Scorpio, the Imperial Agent companion.

Comment: @ZanLynx And the Trooper companion M1-4X, and (since he was patched in) HK-51.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be crafted by cybertech you can also buy them with commendations on some planets, you get like orange droid cores/motors also, some missions give you them as a reward ive done a few missions where i had the option for them. lastly some heavy armor venders sell some orange droid parts